# Customized list view with Checked and unchecked all CheckBox columns by another CheckBox in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

I have  two `CheckBox` checkbox1, checkbox2 in my adapter class. I want that if I Check on `CheckBox` all `CheckBox` in the list should get checked. for example there are 20 `CheckBox` in my `ListView` if I check one, all other 19 should get checked.

**this Adapter class**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {

private List<Friend> myFriends;
private Activity activity;
private int selectedPosition = -1;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Friend> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.activity = context;
    this.myFriends = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate UI from XML file
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
        // get all UI view
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        // set tag for holder
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // if holder created, get tag from view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.checkBox1.setTag(position); // This line is important.
    holder.checkBox2.setTag(position+100);

    holder.friendName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    if (position == selectedPosition) {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

  if( holder.checkBox1.getTag().equals(position)){                    holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox1, position));
   }else{
       holder.checkBox2.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(holder.checkBox2, position));
 }   
     return convertView;
}
 private View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                selectedPosition = position;
            } else {
                selectedPosition = -1;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView friendName;
    private CheckBox checkBox1,checkBox2;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkBox2=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check1);
        friendName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two Boolean flags. `isChecked1` at object level and `isChecked2` at class level(static variable) in your model. which are by default false.

I am assuming `checkbox2` is the one which once checked will change all checkboxes to checked.

now all of you models will have `isChecked1` variable. on click of any `checkbox1` change the `isChecked1` boolean in your model to true on the clicked position. and call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

if user checks on `checkbox2` just change the static variable to true. and call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

In your `getView` method add simple condition that if `isChecked2` is true make all checkbox checked otherwise only make those checked whose model has `isChecked1` true.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Expandable list view instead of list view for this purpose.

```
<ExpandableListView
      android:id="@+id/laptop_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: In ExpandableListView how to achieve my post